# What is the best api/library for Java to use Cassandra?

Tags: java, api, jpa, nosql, cassandra

I'm looking for an API with the following requirements

1. It's simple to use and is concise. It is not bloated.
2. Works with Spring way of doing things, or is at least easy to make it work with Spring
3. Has a Maven repository, preferably it's already in the main repositories
4. Is production-tested, meaning a fair number of people are using it in production applications.

Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[Hector](http://github.com/rantav/hector) and [Pelops](http://code.google.com/p/pelops/) are, as far as I know, the two that are most widely used (4). I dont think any of the two are mavenized (3).  Both should work in a Spring framework environment(2). Your first criteria might be a little bit subjective. I dont find any of these two bloated. You might do, if you do, please tell me.

Comment: Pelops documentation is very poor.

Answer (score 2):

i know this is an old question but I'd like to point future viewer of the question to [Astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax). It's a [very well documented](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wikihttp://) Cassandra API with many examples and support very high level features such as locking and all versions of cql. Astyanax is also [Mavenized](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.astyanax/astyanax).

Answer (score 1):

Kundera is a object-datastore mapping tool for Cassandra, Hbase and MongoDB.

Some of the salient features are:

- JPA 2.0 compliant.
- Column/ super column indexing using lucene.
- Support for entity relationships and JPA queries.
- Cross-datastore persistence

It's hosted here: 
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera