# Which Clojure library for accessing a Cassandra database?

Tags: clojure, cassandra

Some that I am aware of are [vhector](https://github.com/damienlepage/vhector) and [clj-hector](https://github.com/pingles/clj-hector). Actively-maintained libraries preferred. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have first-hand knowledge, but here's a list of Cassandra Clojure libs, sorted by number of GitHub watchers:

http://clojuresphere.herokuapp.com/?sort=watchers&query=cassandra

It also shows when they were last updated. "Actively maintained" can be difficult to gauge. A lib might have an active maintainer even if it hasn't been updated in a long time. The lib may just be sufficiently-featured and bug-free.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [alia](https://github.com/mpenet/alia) for this [clojure-news-feed](http://glennengstrand.info/software/architecture/oss/clojure) and sustaining 20000 inserts per minute with latencies of 8 ms for the mode and 47 ms for the 95 percentile. This is CQL 3.

Answer (score 1):

an update since now cassandra offers cql support:

https://github.com/mpenet/alia is a good choice, it relies on the "official" java-driver from Datastax (using the new native protocol introduced in cassandra 1.2).

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easiest to use the [Java libraries for Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232842/what-is-the-best-api-library-for-java-to-use-cassandra) directly, at least until the Clojure wrappers become more mature.

In general I've found it very easy to use Java libraries directly from Clojure using the various [Java interop features](http://clojure.org/java_interop) that Clojure provides.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Clojurewerkz Cassaforte: http://github.com/clojurewerkz/cassaforte 1.2+ ready library

Here's a getting started guide: http://clojurecassandra.info/articles/getting_started.html